# Repeating a texture with GL_REPEAT without thrashing cache

Tags: opengl, caching, glsl, textures

I am rendering a large layered terrain with a texture array that has normal, roughness, diffuse, and AO maps. However, each piece of terrain is too large to texture in detail (128x128), so I repeat each of the textures by scaling the UV and using GL_REPEAT. When I use a scale, the FPS drops from 170 to 100. Nvidia Nsight reports that the texture cache is used ineffectively.

[image]

As opposed to:

[image]

Here is the important part of the shader:

```
// Uses cache ineffectively
// vec2 coord = data.Texcoord * 16.0; 
vec2 coord = data.Texcoord;

mat.Diffuse = (texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 0)).rgb * alpha.r + texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 5)).rgb * alpha.g);
mat.Normal = data.TBNMatrix * (texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 1)).rgb * alpha.r + texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 6)).rgb * alpha.g);
mat.Metalness = 0;
mat.Roughness = texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 1)).r * alpha.r + texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 7)).r * alpha.g;
mat.AO = texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 2)).r * alpha.r + texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 8)).r * alpha.g;
mat.Alpha = texture(TerrainAtlas, vec3(coord, 0)).a;
```

Is there any way to repeat a texture while using the cache effectively (without doing so manually by increasing texture size)?

Answer (score 0):

I decreased the tileable textures' sizes from 1024x1024 to 256x256 and that seemed to do the trick. Turns out the GPU (GTX 1080 with 2048 KB of L2 cache) ran out of cache space every time repeat.